# I want to Integrate IBM RFT Tool With IBM RTC

Tags: rtc, rft

I have written script using RFT tool , now I Want to integrate it with RTC tool so that Using RTC I can Run My Script From Web page, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation on this integration remains "[Rational Functional Tester and Rational Team Concert](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.7.1/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/c_rft_rtc_integration.html)"

> To manage functional test assets using Rational Team Concert, you must install Rational Team Concert in the same package group as Rational Functional Tester.

That does not tell you about a "web page" though.
The integration is done generally at the Eclipse level, with an [RTC integrated to an Eclipse RCP](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_client_installation_p2.html).
Then, as seen [in this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/247631/rational-functional-tester-eclipse-rcp-plugin-base.html):

> RFT supports testing of applications based on Eclipse 3.0.x, 3.1.x, 3.2.x, 3.3.x, 3.4.x, 3.5.x, 3.6.2, 4.2 and 4.2.2. You must enable the Eclipse platform for testing before recording scripts to test Eclipse-based applications.

Answer (score -1):

The RFT - RTC integration is for source control of RFT assets into RTC. So from the RFT IDE, you can persist your project in source control, retrieve it when you need it.

The ability to execute an RFT test from a web page is provided thru the integration with Rational Quality Manager or RQM described in the [product knowledge center.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBLQQ_9.1.1/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/c_integrate_rqm.html)